# How do I use one single PNG image for multiple sprites?

Tags: java, image, png

How do I use a single PNG image for multiple sprites?
I'm trying to make a simple 2d game and I don't want to have like 20+ different image files.
I just want to put them on one PNG file.

#### Example

The `terrain.png` (and `items.png`) from minecraft has different tiles on it and each of the 16x16 pixel areas are used for a different texture of a block.

Can someone provide some code and an explanation?

Comment: I think that the "some code" part is your responsibility, but you can have a sprite sheet with a grid of sprites on it, read it in as a BufferedImage and then split off sprites from the image using `getSubImage(...)` method of BufferedImage.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/621835/469220

Comment: Thanks to both of you, that has helpd me a lot :D

Comment: This technique is called: texture atlas. :)

Comment: See also [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) in which I carve an image into 9 parts to use as icons for buttons and labels in a `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a Java game a few years back so hopefully can give you some useful advice and code samples..

You can organise your sprites in a single image like this:

https://github.com/mikera/tyrant/blob/master/src/main/resources/images/creature32.png

The example above uses 32x32 sprites, you can use any size you like but it helps to keep them regular.

Then when you draw the screen during the game, you just pick off the respective sprite and draw in in the right location.

Code might look something like this:

```
public void drawImage(Graphics g,double x, double y, int image) {
    int px = (int)((x - scrollx) * TILEWIDTH);
    int py = (int)((y - scrolly) * TILEHEIGHT);
    int sx = (image%20) * TILEWIDTH;
    int sy = TILEHEIGHT * (image/20);
    g.drawImage(sourceImage, px, py, px + TILEWIDTH,
            py + TILEHEIGHT, sx, sy, sx + TILEWIDTH, sy + TILEHEIGHT,
            null);
}
```

Here the `int image` is an index into the position on the sprite sheet to use. Increment by 1 to move one sprite to the right, increment by 20 to move one sprite down in the sprite sheet.

More complete source code available at: https://github.com/mikera/tyrant/blob/master/src/main/java/mikera/tyrant/MapPanel.java